# How do I get redux to add a contact to my contacts state object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, state

I'm building a very simple contacts application to get familiar with React and Redux. Right now I am trying to build the functionality to add a contact. I thought I had the action and reducer set up correctly but currently the state that is getting passed to my reducer is null. I would expect the current list of contacts to be in the state that is passed. If I log the state after the reducer has executed it doesn't even get the one contact that I would expect to be added, it is still empty. When I add some text to the input fields and click "Add Contact" I get an error `Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

In the add contact reducer the state that is getting passed in is null and I think this is my problem. I want this reducer to get the state as the current list of contacts, add to that the contact contained in the payload and return back a new state containing this full list.

My code is as follows

Action:

```
function addContact(contact) {
  console.log("it gets to the action");
  return {
    type: 'ADD_CONTACT',
    payload: contact
  }
}

export default addContact;
```

AddContacts Reducer:

```
export default function (state = {}, action) {
  console.log(state);

  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_CONTACT':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        contacts: [
          ...state.contacts,
          {
            name: action.payload.name,
            phone: action.payload.phone
          }
        ]
      })
  }
  return state;
}
```

Component that invokes this action:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import AddContactButton from './AddContactButton';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import addContact from '../actions/action_add_contact'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'

class AddContactModal extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {firstName: "", phone: ""};
  }

  handleNameChange(event) {
    this.setState({firstName: event.target.value})
  }

  handlePhoneChange(event) {
    this.setState({phone: event.target.value});
  }

  render() {

    return(
      <div>
        <input type="text" className="name" placeholder="Contact Name" onChange={(event) => this.handleNameChange(event)}/>
        <input type="text" className="phone" placeholder="Contact Phone" onChange={(event) => this.handlePhoneChange(event)}/>
        <AddContactButton firstName={this.state.firstName} firstName={this.state.phone} onClick={() => this.props.addContact({"name": this.state.firstName, "phone": this.state.phone})}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    contacts: state.contacts
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ addContact: addContact }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AddContactModal)
```

Store creation:

```
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware()(createStore);
const initialState = {
  "contacts": [
    {
      "name": "Miguel Camilo",
      "phone": "123456789"
    },
    {
      "name": "Peter",
      "phone": "883292300348"
    },
    {
      "name": "Jessica",
      "phone": "8743847638473"
    },
    {
      "name": "Michael",
      "phone": "0988765553"
    }
  ],
  "activeContact": null
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={ createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers, initialState) }>
   <App />
  </Provider>
, document.querySelector('.container'));
```

Contacts reducer that just returns a hard-coded list of contacts to set up the initial state:

```
export default function () {
  return [{
    "name": "Miguel Camilo",
    "phone": "123456789"
  },{
    "name": "Peter",
    "phone": "883292300348"
  },{
    "name": "Jessica",
    "phone": "8743847638473"
  },{
    "name": "Michael",
    "phone": "0988765553"
  }];
}
```

I'm pretty sure my issue is coming from my use of mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps in the component, when I look at the redux state I see it added a collection "addContacts" which I don't think I want? Shouldn't it just take the payload from the action and add this to the "contacts" collection?

In the `mapStateToProps` function I added a print statement to see `state` and this it the result. I'm not sure why that collection `addContact[]` exists. I don't want this, I simply want the addContact functionality to add a contact to the existing `contacts[]` collection.

```
{
  "contacts": [
    {
      "name": "Miguel Camilo",
      "phone": "123456789"
    },
    {
      "name": "Peter",
      "phone": "883292300348"
    },
    {
      "name": "Jessica",
      "phone": "8743847638473"
    },
    {
      "name": "Michael",
      "phone": "0988765553"
    }
  ],
  "activeContact": null,
  "addContact": {}
}
```

Comment: You should add a console.log(state) on your mapStateToProps

Comment: @BenjamínVázquez I added the result of this to my original post

Comment: take a look here: https://redux.js.org/api/bindactioncreators

Answer (score 1):

For your Reducer, try something simpler like this:

```
export default function (state = {}, action) {    
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_CONTACT':
      return {
        ...state,
        contacts: state.contacts.push(action.payload),
      };
  }
};
```

Then for your mapDispatchToProps for simple applications it can work using only an object.

Eg.

```
const actions = { addContact };

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(AddContactModal);
```

OR an update to the current code:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ addContact }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AddContactModal);
```

Hope it helps ;).

I can show you another way to build the store and add it to the Provider. Because the way you did it is different that what I am used to.

Best Regards.